# select multiple entities from database in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to take gender entities(male or female) from database and I want to show it in dropdown box:

Controller:

```
List<Gender> list2 = db.Gender.ToList();
ViewBag.GenderList = new SelectList(list2, "GenderID", "GenderType");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenderID, ViewBag.GenderList as SelectList,"--select--",new { @class="form-control"})
```

Where is my fault ? I need help

Gender Class

```
public class GenderViewModel
{
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    public string GenderN { get; set; }
}
```

Personal Class

```
public class PersonalViewModel
{
    public int PersonalID { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public string PLastname { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string PPassword { get; set; }
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    public int PAuthorisation { get; set; }
    public bool PStatus { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime JobStartDate { get; set; }

    public string GenderType { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you seeing an exception?  What HTML is getting rendered?

Comment: can you show  gender class ???

Comment: i put it above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gender class has GenderN (I presume GenderName?) but is binding to GenderType, so that mismatch alone will cause an exception.  ViewBag is dynamic, so you shouldn't need the cast in the view (since it's evaluated at runtime)...

Change GenderClass:

```
public class GenderViewModel
    {
        public int GenderID { get; set; }
        public string GenderName { get; set; }
    }
```

And change controller:

```
ist<Gender> list2 = db.Gender.ToList();
ViewBag.GenderList = new SelectList(list2, "GenderID", "GenderName");
```

Posting the specific error will help.

Comment: Gender table has relationship with Personal table. I show Personal table too. in this entities , How can i fix it?

Comment: Well how is that table used it's not even used at all in the code sample......  please include that code too..........

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact error you're seeing but I'm sure you can use a ViewBag in-place like that as it is an anonymous object. Assign the ViewBag to a separate variable:

```
@{
   var genderlist = (SelectList)ViewBag.GenderList;
}

@Html.DropDownList("genderID", genderlist, "Gender", new { @class = "classnameifneeded" })
```

Personally, I would do it like this:

**Class/C#/Controller Side:**

```
List<Gender> list2 = db.Gender.ToList();
ViewBag.GenderList = list2;
```

**View Side:**

```
@{
   var genderlist = ViewBag.GenderList;
}

Html.DropDownList("genderID", new SelectList(genderlist, "GenderID", "GenderType", 0), "Gender", new { @class="classnameifneeded" })
```

Answer (score 0):

on html part try:
@Html.DropDownList("GenderList", null, "--select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })